# Show button if meta box has content, else hide

Tags: metabox

I have a meta box setup that allows the article creator to post a link to the forum topic of the same article subject. I display this meta data with the following:

```
<div class="discuss">
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'true_title', true ); ?>">Discuss...</a>
</div>
```

Is there an `if` statement I could use so that if there is meta data to display, then it shows the button, but if not, it simply removes the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if it's empty before you show the div.

```
<?php $true_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'true_title', true ); ?>

<?php if( ! empty( $true_title ) ) : ?>

  <div class="discuss"><a href="<?php echo $true_title;  ?>">Discuss...</a></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```